# Creation of DML Trigger (for Delete)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have four tables in my database: Products, Printers, PC, Laptops. 
In all these tables I have attribute "Model". All models from: Printers, PC and Laptops is in table Products. I need to create a Trigger that interdicts deletion of models that have the price >300 and this models are produced by the "A" manufacturer.

```
select distinct 
    products.model 
from 
    products 
left join 
    PC on products.model = PC.model
left join 
    laptops on products.model = laptops.model
left join 
    printers on products.model = printers.model 
where 
    manufacturer = 'A' 
    and (PC.price > 300 or laptops.price > 300 or printers.price > 300);
```

This `SELECT` returns the models that satisfy this conditions. I tried to create a DML Trigger.
**[1]**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TASK3 
ON products  
FOR DELETE
AS
   IF ((SELECT deleted.model FROM deleted) 
       IN (select products.model 
           from products 
           left join PC on products.model = PC.model
           left join laptops on products.model = laptops.model
           left join printers on products.model = printers.model 
           where manufacturer = 'A' 
             and (PC.price > 300 or laptops.price > 300 or printers.price > 300))) 
    begin
        raiserror ( 'This model can't be deleted, because price is greater than 300 and manufacturer is 'A',2,1)
        rollback transaction;
    end
    else 
         print 'That model will be deleted'
```

I tried to compare the attribute value that will be deleted (from deleted table) with values returned by SELECT like **[1]**, in case if the value is met in the list of models that respect this condition (price>300 && manufacturer = 'A') then the Trigger to interdict his deletion.

Comment: What is your question?  Does your existing code not work in some way or produce an error?

Comment: The existing code doesn't reproduce the error and does delete every model even if it has the price>300 && manufacturer="A".

Comment: THANKS A LOT ;) this does work for me ! @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

Note that in SQL Server, deletions can affect multiple records.  So, your first subquery can cause a problem of returning too many records.

If you want to prevent the execution of the entire `delete` when even one record fails, then:

```
if (exists (select 1
            from deleted d
            where d.manufacturer = 'A' and
                  (exists (select 1 from pc p where p.model = d.model and p.price > 300) or
                   exists (select 1 from laptops l where l.model = d.model and l.price > 300) or
                   exists (select 1 from printers p where p.model = d.model and p.price > 300)
                  )
          )
    )
begin
    raiseerror . . .
end;
   )
```